# How to validate Java API @HeaderParam before execution of method

Tags: java, json, api, validation, http-headers

I have this endpoint method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update")
public ResponseEntity(Response) update(
        @ApiParam(required=true) @Valid @RequestBody Request request,
        @RequestHeader @HeaderParam("key") String key
    ){

    //execution of code here

    return null;
}
```

I'm currently validating the Request Body using a custom JSON Deserializer.

Is there anyway that I could validate the Header Param "key" similar to the way I would validate a Request Body using a JSON Deserializer?

Maybe something like this that would execute before the "//execution of code here":

```
@Override
public String deserialize(String key){
    if(!key.equals("ABC")){
        throw new Exception("key is wrong");
    }
    return key;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you want to validate it inside the function?

Comment: @dehasi i feel like it'd be cleaner this way.